# Nested http requests with map with rxjs in Angular2

Tags: angular, gitlab, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm new to Rxjs (and Angular2 in general) and I'm having trouble understanding the subtleties of RxJS.

I want to make two REST calls to the GitLab API:

1. Receive all the groups of a certain user (via gitlab.com/api/v4/groups). this will give me back a JSON like this one:

   ```
   [
   {
       "id": 1511397,
       "name": "some name",
       "parent_id": 1505403,
   ...
   },
   {
       "id": 1511403,
       "name": "some other name",
       "parent_id": 1505403,
   ...
   }
   ]
   ```
2. Receive all the projects of per group (via gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/:id) which give you a detailed version of 1 group:

   ```
   {
   "id": 1511397,
   "name": "group name",
   "parent_id": 1505403,
   "projects": [
       {
           "id": 3099499,
           "description": "project 1"
       },
       {
           "id": 3099489,
           "description": "Project 2"
       }
   ]
   }
   ```

So basically I need to loop over all ID's given by the first request and deliver an array of group-details:

```
[
 {
 "id": 1511397,
 "name": "group name",
 "parent_id": 1505403,
 "projects": [
     {
         "id": 3099499,
         "description": "project 1"
     },
     {
         "id": 3099489,
         "description": "Project 2"
     }
 ]
 },
 {
 "id": 1194997,
 "name": "a second group name",
 "parent_id": 152393,
 "projects": [
     {
         "id": 9423423,
         "description": "project 3"
     },
     {
         "id": 2394238,
         "description": "Project 4"
     }
 ]
 }
]
```

How can this be done? I already tried something along the lines of switchMap, concatMap and MergeMap, but I never can get it to work...

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
getGroups() {
  return this.http.get('gitlab.com/api/v4/groups')
    .map(res => res.json()) // convert to object[]
    .map(res => res.map(g => g.id)) // get all id
    .mergeMap(gid => {
      let gs = [];
      gid.forEach(id => {
        let req = this.http.get(`gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/${id}`);
        gs.push(req);
      });
      return Observable.forkJoin(gs);
    })
    .map(res => { // we have array of Response Object
        return res.map(x => x.json()); // Array.map not Observable map operator.
    });
}

getGroups().subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that. You need to replace static Observable.of to $http observables.

```
Rx.Observable.of([{userId:1}, {userId:2}])
.switchMap(ids => Rx.Observable.of(...ids))
.mergeMap(userId => {
 return Rx.Observable.of([
   {userId:userId, name:'project1'},
   {userId:userId, name:'project2'}
 ]);
})
.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

1. Rx.Observable.of([{userId:1}, {userId:2}]) - is like http call that gives u array of users
   2 .switchMap(ids => Rx.Observable.of(...ids)) - for each user you create a separate observable
2. .mergeMap for each user observable you call $http to get projects.